# Laravel Scribe issues (model route binding in FormRequests and generation error)

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, scribe

I faced with route model binding error while generating documentation:

[image]

This issue appears in few routes (not in all, only where i`m calling model from route for data validation). I`we tried to bind models manually with normalizeEndpointUrlUsing() like so

```
            Scribe::normalizeEndpointUrlUsing(
                function (string           $url, Route $route, ReflectionFunctionAbstract $method,
                          ?ReflectionClass $controller, callable $default
                ) {

                    return match ($url) {

                        'api/v1/admins/advertisers/{advertiser}' => 'api/v1/admins/advertisers/' . Advertiser::first()->id,

                        default => $default(),
                    };
                });
```

Also tried to set in the same way in instantiateFormRequestUsing() like auth()->user() instance

No effect.

In the end of php artisan scribe:generate command also have Undefined array key "PATH" error
[image]

Also, i have issue with auth routes, im using Sanctum SPA auth and tried to set scrf cookie, but no effect, them throws an unauthorized error in doc. I starte to use Bearer token in Authorization header, but maybe there is a way to set csrf-cookie.

Config has no any non-standard issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get any solutions for that,

Comment: did you fix this? I have same issue on update request